# How would I sort averages by row and/or column of an array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, average, mean

I've been having trouble with finding the average of an array of lists, specifically by row and by column. I know what I want to do with it, but I'm struggling with finding what kind of code to write for it. The array is as follows:

```
data = [[126, 91, 43],
[534, 59, 148],
[53, 78, 1],
[725, 727, 729],
[0, 12, 0],
[64, 23, 3]]
```

By row, I want to essentially find the averages of each individual list within this array without combining them. By column, I want to find the averages of the x'th item in each list within the array. What I want to code is as follows:
By row: find how many lists there are in the array, then calculate their means individually. The index range would be unlimited.
By column: find how many lists there are in the array, take only the x'th terms from each list, and calculate their means. The index range would be unlimited.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: These sorts of operations are simple (and faster) in a numpy array which uses a contiguous block of memory to store the data. Especially for a large data set that would be a good approach. Slices can be taken of columns or rows as required.

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? At least you could try to use `for`-loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
import statistics

data = [
    [126, 91, 43],
    [534, 59, 148],
    [53, 78, 1],
    [725, 727, 729],
    [0, 12, 0],
    [64, 23, 3],
]

row_average = [statistics.fmean(x) for x in data]
print(row_average)  # [86.66666666666667, 247.0, 44.0, 727.0, 4.0, 30.0]
column_average = [statistics.fmean(x) for x in zip(*data)]
print(column_average)  # [250.33333333333334, 165.0, 154.0]
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! For future reference, though, how would I translate that to logic in the event that I wouldn't use import statistics?

Comment: That's a great question. To forgo the statistics package, you can borrow from @Deepak Tripathi's solution with: `[sum(x)/len(x) for x in data]` and `[sum(x)/len(x) for x in zip(*data)]`

Answer (score 2):

For row wise

```
[sum(i)/len(i) for i in data]
```

For colum wise

```
[sum(i)/len(i) for i in zip(*data)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Some good answers here, but you could do this with numpy to avoid the iterators

```
import numpy as np
data = [
    [126, 91, 43],
    [534, 59, 148],
    [53, 78, 1],
    [725, 727, 729],
    [0, 12, 0],
    [64, 23, 3],
]

np.mean(data, axis=1) # mean of each row
np.mean(data, axis=0) # mean of each column
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from statistics import mean

print(*map(mean, zip(*data)))
```

Output

```
250.33333333333334 165 154
```

or else

```
avg_each_list = [float(sum(data))/len(data) for data in zip(*data)]
print(avg_each_list )
```

output

```
[250.33333333333334, 165.0, 154.0]
```